# UITableViewCell content is sometimes overlapped by delete button (on swipe)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe, ios11

I've implemented swipe to delete in UITableView a lot of times before, but never faced this problem before. In my last app delete button sometimes (not always) doesn't shift cell's content, but just overlaps it. See attached screenshot.

[image]

I use standard iOS functionality for this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Probably, somebody already faced with this issue and know how to fix it?